# Credit card expiry date with slash problem

Tags: javascript

Credit card expiration date: `mm/yy`
Whenever I enter two numbers, I need add `/`, but currently when I delete the third number, he will only delete one number. How can I delete the third number along with the slash?

Please help thank you.

```js
var characterCount
$('#expiry').on('input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length == 2 && characterCount < $(this).val().length) {
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
  }
  characterCount = $(this).val().length
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="expiry" type="text" />
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `vue`, but `jquery` - did you mix up the tags?

Comment: Swapped vuejs for jquery tag

Comment: Sorry because I am a vue project but I don’t know how to write in vue, so I use jquery first

Answer (score 1):

with plain js

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('#expiry')

inp.onkeydown = function() {

  const key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  
  if (key !== 8 && key !== 46 ) {
    if (inp.value.length == 2) {
        inp.value= (inp.value+'/');
    }
  }
  
  if (( key == 8 || key == 46 ) && inp.value.length === 4) {
    inp.value = inp.value.slice(0,3)
  }    
};
```

```html
<input id="expiry" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this method can delete / smoothly, but there is no way to delete the first two numbers

Comment: Sorry mate, my bad, i corrected result, try now :)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to enter the second digit and add "/", now it becomes the third digit to add "/"

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional `keyup` event and when the backspace key is hit, remove any trailing slash from the end of the value.

I'd also recommend to set the [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmaxlength), [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) and [`inputmode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) attributes on the input.

```js
var characterCount;
$('#expiry').on('input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length == 2 && characterCount < $(this).val().length) {
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
  }
  characterCount = $(this).val().length
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 8) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\/$/, ''))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="expiry" type="text" maxlength="5" pattern="^\d{2}/\d{2}$" inputmode="numeric" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This method can delete the "/" smoothly, but when there are two digits left after the deletion, the "/" is no longer entered